# request post from ajax asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to retrieve the post parameter sent in the controller:

**Ajax function:**

```
function ajaxCall(AjaxUrl, type, param1) {
var url = AjaxUrl;
var SendType = type;

if (param1 == null)
    var param1 = '';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: SendType,
    data: {param1: param1},
    DataType: "html"
});
```

}

**controller:**

```
string fullPath = request.POST[''];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using :`NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;`

You can then get `nvc['param1]`

Comment: Why would one do that in normal MVC code? Parameters normally passed as arguments to actions...

Comment: This code can be used anywhere i guess and more control .
But in the actual controller u can just use the arguments..

Comment: I was using a parameter but as it is a POST the parameter is not sending using a URL. I was getting  NOT FOUND from the server. Why would I use Request.Form if I don´t have a form. It is just a parameter. Am I mixing up any concept?

Comment: Thanks. Worked this way. I am just curious why I am getting a NOT FOUND using a action parameter.